# Shopify - Retrieves multiple variant detail by multiple variant id

Tags: php, shopify, variant

Is there any way to get multiple variant details using multiple variant id in single shopify call.
Actually, I want to get price of all product variant which are listed in order using shopify call.

I know following way for get single variant detail using id

GET /admin/variants/#{variant_id}.json

/admin/variants/808950810.json

Answer (score 2):

If you want the price of all the variants of a product, make one API call, and use the product ID. You'll get back all the variants, making it trivial to iterate through them to get prices.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Currently working as you describe, But i am asking there is any way to get detail by multiple variant id like multiple product id.

Comment: No. The relation is product has many variants.Variants are a leaf node. End of story.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment of writing, you can only retrieve all variants for a product via [Shopify API](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/products/product-variant#index-2021-04).

If you're looking for retrieving unrelated, it's not possible via the API now.

But I think it's possible to submit multiple concurrent requests using a task queue or async requests. I'm also trying to speed up getting several variants at once.